# Setting up multiple CM servers

Tags: best-practices, scaling

We are setting up multiple Sitecore CM servers.

Do we need to do anything more then what is covered in [this](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server) documentation for setting up CMs. The documentation covers just giving each instance of CM a unique name.

> sc8CM1
>
> If you have multiple CM servers, give each a unique name, such as:
>
> - sc8CM2
> - sc8CM3

So what else is there to be aware of, I would particularly be keen to know about:-

- Will the CM systems conflict in anyway?
- I would like to know if it is preferred to run Tasks from one CM and not both.
- How do we manage syncing content between the two?
- I would appreciate any other advice, if I have missed something make me aware.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, and I do believe your question is valid. But I also think you would do well to maybe elaborate a bit on your question. The managing of jobs and agents is indeed something to be considered, but also settings such as allowing file based media uploads and likely lots more.

Comment: I think this question is to broad; there is no clear problem which might lead to a small set of answers. For these kind of issues, I would kindly redirect you to the Sitecore documentation. It's not my downvote as well btw ;)

Comment: I updated question, capturing your original thoughts and points and adding some my own. Hoping to get reopened and I will add a bounty on it. I think there is a lot that can be covered and the community could benefit from this information.

Comment: Maybe we could split this question up in to several more specific ones and link them together somehow?

Comment: We could ask individual questions and in the next questions say this is follow on from this previous question?

Comment: We end up with a walk through of questions and answers?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has got downvoted so much - It's similar to a lot of other best practice questions I've seen.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, either. I think whatever issue with the post lead to the downvotes (content maybe?) must have been resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to have only one database. In other words, if you have 3 CM Servers, all of them should be connected to the same database.

For running of tasks, that is, scheduled jobs, you can setup one of your CM server as the job server. All the jobs will be performed only on one server (job server). If you are using the same database, all the CM will have the same content, hence enabling your CM Servers to be in sync.

Moreover, you will need to make use of event queue. So you need to make sure that the event queue setting is set to true in the Sitecore.config file found in the App_Config folder if you are using Sitecore 8 or check in the web.config if you are using Sitecore 6.x to 7.x. You also need to configure your Scalability Setting since you have have one CM Server which will act as the job server. More information on how to setup the Scalability setting can be found at my blogpost [here](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/sitecore-scalability-setting/)

Comment: When you dedicate one of the servers to handling jobs like this, can you still use that server for handling regular editing requests, or should it not be accessible to editors?

Comment: You may still let your editors to perform item changes on the job server as it is like a CM server but it beat the purpose of having a job server to serve jobs requests.

Comment: Why do we need to use the event queue?

Comment: @Ayushmati you use event queue so that when events are triggered Sitecore looks into the event queue and triggers that particular events on the other servers. More info https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sitecore-event-queues/amp/