# Configuring multiple CM servers with DFS synchronisation

Tags: publishing, scaling, load-balancer

I have a setup with two CM servers (I know, 3 would be better...) and want to designate one as the publishing/task server. I have read this question and answer [Setting up multiple CM servers](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/setting-up-multiple-cm-servers) but my scenario is slightly different in that the CM servers use DFS to synch the file systems.

Must I disable DFS and use different configs for each server, or is it possible to use the same config on both servers (they are named CM01 and CM02):

```
<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
  <patch:attribute name="value">CM02</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to disable the DFS. Because the Job Server (publishing/task) will mainly deals with Sitecore Items while the DFS is used for the files synchronization.

One thing to keep in mind is that when using the DFS, you will have a master server along with slave servers. So, file deployment should be performed on the Master Server so that it gets synchronized on the slave servers.

Comment: So do you confirm that it is harmless for the CM02 machine to have the `Publishing.PublishingInstance` setting set to itself.

Comment: Yes. But just make sure that your scalability setting is setup properly.

Comment: The Scalability config will need to be different. The Instance Name (Different from PublishingInstance) must be different for each server.

Comment: @PeteNavarra AFAIK if the InstanceName field is left blank, then Sitecore defaults to Machine Name + IIS SiteName (see here http://www.newguid.net/sitecore/2012/configure-a-authoring-server-as-publishing-instance/).

Comment: Yep, you are correct. In that case you'll want to make sure your publishing instance also includes the appropriate machine name and iis sitename.  I saw CM02 in the question thinking you needed to use custom instance names.  =)

Comment: I didn't use the _real_ names for the question, but I do indeed need to include the IIS site name on the end ;-)