# Null reference exception on Clicking item in Content Tree

Tags: content-editor

I'm facing null reference issue with multiple CM Sitecore Setup. Below is the environment details.

Servers 2

Sitecore 8.0 update 6

Very minimal access to infrastructure.

**DisableClientBrowsing is set to true.**

**Scalability Setting config is disabled.**

> ERROR Application error. Exception:
>   System.Web.HttpUnhandledException Message: Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. Source: System.Web
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
>   ASP.sitecore_shell_applications_content_manager_default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET Files\root\68275d57\e975e24f\App_Web_py4csts0.3.cs:line 0
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Message:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Source:
>   mscorlib    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target,
>   Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method,
>   Object[] parameters, Object obj)    at
>   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException Message: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object. Source: Sitecore.Client    at
>   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e)

Comment: Please include stack traces as quoted text for the search engines; not images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scalability Settings configuration *must* be enabled for a multiple CM setup.

What most likely happens here is, that you're clicking a content item that the CM that has since been deleted on one of the *other* CM instances but the change has not been reflected. This is what Scalability Settings does for you.

You must also ensure your EventQueues are enabled. I believe Scalability Settings config does this, but double check it to be sure.

More info: [Setting up multiple CM servers](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/setting-up-multiple-cm-servers)

Comment: I have enabled Scalability Settings file on both CM servers and now have unique instance name like SCCM1 and SCCM2. I am still facing the same issue. Do you know the name of Event Queue settings. I'm unable to find the same.

Answer (score 0):

@Mohit Dharmadhikari

```
<setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true"/>
```

It is under Sitecore.config you can refer https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2011/03/19/basics-of-sitecore-event-queue/ blog for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks. This setting is already set to  true in my application.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer? Right now, it doesn't say what you should do with the piece of XML you posted. So you're getting dangerously close to a [**link-only answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/183720).